# How does the PolkadotApps get the lease period?

Tags: polkadot-js, auctions

On the parachain auction page. IIUC, there isn't any on-chain storage to store these values. How can I get that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is correct.

It reads from the `auctions.winning: Option<[Option<(AccountId32,u32,u128)>;36]>`.

And the result is:

```
[
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      [
        xxx
        xxx
        xxx
      ]
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
      null
]
```

According to the slot range:

```
// pub enum SlotRange {
//  ZeroZero,       0
//  ZeroOne,        1
//  ZeroTwo,        2
//  ZeroThree,      3
//  ZeroFour,       4
//  ZeroFive,       5
//  ZeroSix,        6
//  ZeroSeven,      7
//  OneOne,         8
//  OneTwo,         9
//  OneThree,       10
//  OneFour,        11
//  OneFive,        12
//  OneSix,         13
//  OneSeven,       14
//  TwoTwo,         15
//  TwoThree,       16
//  TwoFour,        17
//  TwoFive,        18
//  TwoSix,         19
//  TwoSeven,       20
//  ThreeThree,     21
//  ThreeFour,      22
//  ThreeFive,      23
//  ThreeSix,       24
//  ThreeSeven,     25
//  FourFour,       26
//  FourFive,       27
//  FourSix,        28
//  FourSeven,      29
//  FiveFive,       30
//  FiveSix,        31
//  FiveSeven,      32
//  SixSix,         33
//  SixSeven,       34
//  SevenSeven,     35
// }
```

It's `OneSeven`. And this auction's start index is `30`.

So, `30 + 1 ~ 30 + 7`.

Answer (score 5):

So for clarity we wrote out a lot of parachain auctions, leases, crowdloan logic in [`substrate-api-sidecar`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/blob/master/src/services/paras/ParasService.ts) to which you can checkout if you want more information about what you can query and grab.

Okay so to the question above, here is some code to get the leasePeriods.

```js
const apiAt = api.at(<some_block_hash>);

const auctionInfoOpt = apiAt.query.auctions.auctionInfo<Option<Vec<BlockNumber>>>();

let leasePeriodIndex: BlockNumber | null;
if (auctionInfoOpt.isSome) {
    [leasePeriodIndex, _] = auctionInfoOpt.unwrap();
}

const leasePeriodsPerSlot = apiAt.consts.auctions.leasePeriodsPerSlot.toNumber()

const leasePeriods = leasePeriodIndex !== null
    ? Array(leasePeriodsPerSlot)
            .fill(0)
            .map((_, i) => i + (leasePeriodIndex as BN).toNumber())
    : null;

console.log(leasePeriods)
```

This will yield a result like:

```
[
        "31",
        "32",
        "33",
        "34",
        "35",
        "36",
        "37"
]
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated the screenshot. I mean a parachain could also bid for `31 ~ 35`, `32 ~ 33`, `30`, etc. Your algorithm just count the leases.

Comment: @AurevoirXavier Ahh okay makes sense thanks for updating the picture, AFAIK if you want to get the leases for a specific parachain you can use `apiAt.query.slots.leases(<para_id>)` which will return the type: `Vec<Option<ITuple<[AccountId, BalanceOf]>>>`.

You can take then take the size of that vector, and increment from the current leasePeriodIndex. On ways to calculate the index you can find that [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/blob/master/src/services/paras/ParasService.ts#L488-L502).